# Using DjangoObjectPermissionsFilter to filter objects of user using django-guardian

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-guardian

I was able to setup `django-guardian` and my `django-rest-framework` project as the [example in drf docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangoobjectpermissionsfilter), but I'm failing to achieve the behavior that I want. Could someone please point out if I'm doing something wrong or if what I want can't be done with `guardian`?

**Setup**

settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'guardian',
    'simple',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)

'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'infrastructure.permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions',
)
```

infrastructure.permissions.py

```python
from rest_framework import permissions


class DjangoObjectPermissions(permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions):
    """
    Similar to `DjangoObjectPermissions`, but adding 'view' permissions.
    """
    perms_map = {
        'GET': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'OPTIONS': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'HEAD': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'POST': ['%(app_label)s.add_%(model_name)s'],
        'PUT': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'PATCH': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'DELETE': ['%(app_label)s.delete_%(model_name)s'],
    }
```

models.py

```python
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    min_age = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        permissions = (('view_event', 'Can view event'),)
```

views.py

```python
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.EventSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoObjectPermissionsFilter,)
```

**Expected behavior**

- The list of `Events` returned by `EventViewSet.list` contains only objects that the request user can view (request user has django.auth `view_event` permission OR `('view_event', event_object)`.
- `EventViewSet.details` returns the `Event` instance only if the request user has the `view_event` permission OR the `('view_event', event_object)` permission.

**Actual behavior**

- If the user has the django auth permission `view_event` and the guardian permission `('view_event', event_obj)`, it can access the routes `list` (getting all entries) and `details` associated with the `event_obj`.
- If the user DOESN'T have the auth permission `view_event`, but has the guardian permission `('view_event', event_obj)`, they receive a 403 in all routes (including the `details` route associated with the event_obj that they have permission over).
- If the user has `view_event` but doesn't have `('view_event', event_obj)`, they can access the route `list` (seeing all entries), but they receive a 404 in `details` route, regardless the entry being accessed.

Thank you!

Comment: I started to play with guardian and I see this same behaviour. But I didn't try with `filter_backends` so I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, turns out that all views with permission class `DjangoObjectPermissions` will only allow users to see a given resource if they have **model-level and object-level** permissions. The fact that my users are being able to list all objects, but not retrieving any of them, is because of a [known bug](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3163) that was already corrected but isn't on the current release just yet.